# getting valid JSON in Nodejs from Posted data

Tags: node.js

am getting `json` data as a response in the following format

```
{ '{"select":"samplec","value":"nation"}': '' }
```

How can i get a valid json data like

```
'{"select":"samplec", "value": "nation"}'
```

Comment: Are you using Express (or any other framework)?

Comment: not using express frame work

Comment: i used json.parse but getting `undefined:1
([object Object])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is sort of an odd response to be getting, but in any case for this particular example you would do something like:

```
// Get the keys of your weird response object
var keys = Object.keys(response);
// The first key is a JSON string, so parse that
var obj = JSON.parse(keys[0]);
```

If the response had more than one key, you could loop through them all and create an array of objects. I would look into why the response was formatted the way it is, though, and see if you can't get the JSON strings delivered in some other way.